# Is the concept of Matrix Scalar Multiplication the same as scalar multiplications done during row operations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I would like to know the meaning and implications of scalar multiplication during row operations, as well as general scalar multiplication of Matrices, and the difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just look at the $2\times 2$ case.  Consider the matrix
$$X = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\c & d
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
If for a scalar $\alpha$, we compute $\alpha X$,the result is $$\alpha X = \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha a & \alpha b\\\alpha c & \alpha d
\end{pmatrix},$$ that is *every* element of $X$ is multiplied by $\alpha$.  We can also express this as $$\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & 0\\0 & \alpha \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\c & d
\end{pmatrix}. $$  If we do the row operation
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\c & d
\end{pmatrix}\overset{\alpha R_{1}\to R_{1}}\longrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha a & \alpha b\\c & d
\end{pmatrix}$$ then in terms of matrix multiplication, what we are really doing is computing $$\begin{pmatrix}\alpha & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\c & d
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha a & \alpha b\\c & d
\end{pmatrix}.$$

So in some sense, we can think of general scalar multiplication as the row operation that multiplies *every* row by the same scalar simultaneously, whereas the general row operation for scalar multiplication only multiplies certain rows by certain scalars.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I do want to ask, what does a row multiplication imply? For general scalar multiplication I can think of it as stretching a vector maybe, but not really sure about row operations. Also, are the matrices derived before and after such a row multiplication the same, or are they different? If they are same, how does that work?

Comment: Multiplying by $\alpha I$ stretches the vectors by $\alpha$ in each direction, whereas multiplying by $\begin{pmatrix}\alpha & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ would only stretch the vectors in the first component by $\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't much relation that I can see.  We can view scalar multiplication as multiplication by a *scalar matrix*, that is a diagonal matrix where all the diagonal elements are equal.  $$\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&a\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}w&x\\y&z\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}aw&ax\\ay&az\end{bmatrix}$$
The scalar multiplication you use in row operations is a bit different
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\a&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}w&x\\y&z\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}w&x\\aw+y&ax+z\end{bmatrix}$$

I don't know if this will help you, but I hope it does.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I do want to ask, what does a row multiplication imply? For general scalar multiplication I can think of it as stretching a vector maybe, but not really sure about row operations. Also, are the matrices derived before and after such a row multiplication the same, or are they different? If they are same, how does that work?

Comment: The matrices are different.  Two matrices are the same iff they have the same elements.  The first question depends on WHY you're doing the operation in the first place.  Typically we do these operations to get a matrix that is simpler in some sense but preserves some property of the original matrix, for example the rank.  So, multiplying a row by a non-zero scalar preserves the rank.  But that isn't the only reason we do row operations, so that isn't the answer.